# xxhdpi devices with the screen height of 640 dp use xhdpi rather than h640dp-xhdpi

Tags: android, android-resources, dpi

I have resources in the following folders:

**values-xhdpi**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="test_str">values-xhdpi</string>

    <style name="test">
        <item name="android:background">#aaaaff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-mdpi**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="test_str">values-mdpi</string>

    <style name="test">
        <item name="android:background">#ffaaaa</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-sw600dp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="test_str">values-sw600dp</string>

    <style name="test">
        <item name="android:background">#aaffaa</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-h640dp-xhdpi**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="test_str">values-h640dp-xhdpi</string>

    <style name="test">
        <item name="android:background">#cacaca</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I run a test app with these resources on Nexus 5. The screen density is xxhdpi, and the smallest width is 360 dp. (1920 * 1080 px = 640 * 360 dp).

The flowchart of how Android finds the best-matching resource:

[image: The flowchart of how Android finds the best-matching resource]

---

My configuration qualifier names should be examined in the following order (see *Table 2. Configuration qualifier names* [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)):

- smallestWidth;
- Available height;
- Screen pixel density (dpi).

---

Let's examine *smallestWidth* and eliminate the resources that contradict the device configuration:

values-xhdpi

values-mdpi

<s>values-sw600dp</s>

values-h640dp-xhdpi.

---

Let's examine *Available height* and eliminate the resources that contradict the device configuration:

<s>values-xhdpi</s>

<s>values-mdpi</s>

values-h640dp-xhdpi.

So now `values-h640dp-xhdpi` is the only resource folder left. Let me show you how I apply the resources:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/test"
    android:text="@string/test_str"
    android:textSize="46sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

However, when I run my app on Nexus 5, it uses the resources from `values-xhdpi`. Why?

[image]

---

**Update #1**

This is where I was wrong:

> Let's examine *Available height* and eliminate the resources that
>   contradict the device configuration:
>
> <s>values-xhdpi</s>
>
> <s>values-mdpi</s>
>
> values-h640dp-xhdpi.

*values-h640dp-xhdpi* is eliminated due to a contradiction (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32308323/1065835) which explains why), and *values-mdpi* and *values-xhdpi* are left. The density of Nexus 5 is xxhdpi, but there is no resource specified for xxhdpi. So the best match would be the resource for a smaller screen, xhdpi.

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> Specifically, when selecting resources based on the size qualifiers,
>   the system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the
>   current screen if there are no resources that better match (for
>   example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen resources if
>   necessary). However, if the only available resources are larger than
>   the current screen, the system will not use them and your application
>   will crash if no other resources match the device configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In documentation we can see

> When your application provides multiple resource directories with
>   different values for this configuration, the system uses the one
>   closest to (**without exceeding**) the device's current screen height.

Nexus 5 screen height is 567, but your height is 640, thats why Android exclude this folder.

Answer (score -1):

Nexus 5 is :- 445 ppi pixel density

Samsung Galaxy Nexus I9250 :- 316 ppi pixel density

That why It's Uses the Resources from value-xhdpi.

values-h640dp-xhdpi - Samsung Galaxy Nexus I9250

value-xhdpi - Nexus 5

Comment: ppi is _not_ the same as dpi. http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php - 445 ppi. `adb shell wm density` outputs `Physical density: 480` dpi